# How to concatenate regex patterns?

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, replace

I'm trying to replace text in an html file using a dictionary.

This works but unfortunately doesn't match the text if it's surrounded by an html tag or has a comma next to it:

```
for key in dictionary:
    print(key)
    if key in answer_string:
        pattern = re.compile(key, re.IGNORECASE)
        answer_string = re.sub(r"[^ ]*"+pattern+r"[^ ]*", "<a href=\"" + dictionary.get(key) + "\">" + key + "</a>", answer_string)
```

This is what I tried but doesn't work. I get the error: `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and '_sre.SRE_Pattern' objects`

```
for key in dictionary:
    print(key)
    if key in answer_string:
        pattern = re.compile(key, re.IGNORECASE)
        answer_string = re.sub(r"[^ ]*"+pattern+r"[^ ]*", "<a href=\"" + dictionary.get(key) + "\">" + key + "</a>", answer_string)
```

Answer (score 2):

`re.compile` returns a regex compile object, not a string.  You just need to concatenate your strings before you compile:

```
for key in dictionary:
    print(key)
    if key in answer_string:
        pattern = re.compile(r"[^ ]*"+key+r"[^ ]*", re.IGNORECASE)
        answer_string = pattern.sub("<a href=\"" + dictionary.get(key) + "\">" + key + "</a>", answer_string)
```